# SQL Select statement construction

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table T with

```
|rowid| fld1 | fld2|
|1    |  1   | 10  |
|2    |  1   | 20  |
|3    |  2   | 10  |
|4    |  3   | 20  |
```

if I want to get all the fld1 values with fld2 = 10 AND fld2 = 20.

This would only be fld1 - the only one with fld2 values 10 and 20.

Is my best way to go a subquery:

```
select * from T where fld2 = 10 and rowid in (select rowid from T where fld2 = 20);
```

or is there a better query?

Comment: What you are trying to say is you want to return rowid 1 and 2 because fld1 matches 10 and 20 for fld2

Comment: Yes.  I really just need the fld1 value of 1 because fld1=1 is the only one where there is an fld2 of "10" and one of "20".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I have understood your question

```
select * from table where fld1 in (
select fld1 from table
where fld2 in (10,20)
group by fld1
having count(distinct(fld2)) = 2)
```

If you don't need to retrieve all rows

```
select fld1 from table
where fld2 in (10,20)
group by fld1
having count(distinct(fld2)) = 2
```

this query suffices.

Comment: The group by was what I was forgetting.  Your second query is really what I want.  But is this faster than my subquery?

Comment: I think my query would be faster than your since doesn't use in but you would have to test it with a large dataset and then checking explain of both queries.

Answer (score 4):

You can try a self-join:

```
select * 
from T t1 JOIN T t2 on t1.fld1 = t2.fld1
where t1.fld2 = 10 
and t2.fld2 = 20
```

I not sure on the relative performance of this vs @nick's solution

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE fld2 = '10' AND fld='20'
```

It really is that simple.

Comment: Wait - what exactly do you want to do? fld2 can never be 10 AND 20, and I therefore assumed you wanted where fld1 is 10 and fld2 is 20

Comment: SELECT fld1 FROM T WHERE fld2='10' OR fld2='20' will return all fields where fld2 is 10 or 20. One field can never have two values!

Comment: What you are saying in this query is "Give me every row such that, in that row, `fld2` is 10 and `fld2` is also 20" - so it can never return anything.  The OP needs to apply a condition that correlates multiple rows together - and `SELECT` from a single table with no aggregation can't ever give you that.